# How to fetch only a specified field from pivot with "with" function

Tags: php, laravel, pivot-table, builder, eager-loading

I'm using Laravel 6.0 anc i can't figure out how to fetch just a specified field from the pivot table with the `with` eager loading.

For the relationships i use

```
$builder->with('relation_name:field1,field2")
```

But it doesn't work for the pivot of that relation.
Is there any way to do it or have i got to unset the others fields manually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For relations, the `withPivot()` method on the relationship is probably what you are looking for:

```
 $builder->with(['relation_name' => function ($query) {
      $query->withPivot('field1')->withPivot('field2');
 }])->get();
```

You can combine, but for clarity, this is simplest.

Comment: this does not prevent to be fetched also the other fields from the pivot table

Comment: or at least, from the documentation it should, but i can still see the created at and updated at in the pivot

Comment: I see.  What are you trying to accomplish, reduce the data queried?  IE like a select on the pivots?

Comment: yes,i need to serialize the minimum data possible, and created_at ad updated_at occupy a lot of space... i can use "relation:pivot_field" to add to the model the pivot field value, but then i can't delete the pivot from the models

Comment: OK, if you have the pivot set up on the relationship, you can try `$builder->with('relation_name.pivot.field1')`  By the docs, the thing I showed above should work, so I'm not sure if this will do any more for you, but it might.  I don't think they included the created_at when thinking about pivots.  You can possibly create a mutator to get this, but I'm thinking there must be a better way.

Comment: Call to undefined relationship [pivot] on model... i think i'll have to write a for loop :-(

Comment: Shoot.  Sorry, I think the methods were created within Laravel to select the pivots and the created_at/updated_at unfortunately.  I am out of answers, I'm sorry.